# WPF Datepicker event handler for PowerShell

Tags: wpf, powershell, datepicker

I am trying to add an event handler to a date picker `WPF control` in PowerShell to trigger an event when the user selects a date. I tried following but it didn't work. Does anyone know what is the correct event handler for date picker to use in PowerShell?

```
$dpDate.Add_SelectedDateChanged({ do-something-here })
```

The code snippet is below:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="dpDate" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="105" Focusable="false"/>

$dpDate.Add_SelectedDateChanged
    ({ 
        $DateFormat = get-date $dpDate.SelectedDate -f yyy-MM-dd
        $tb_FinalDate.text = $DateFormat
    })
```

Comment: What kind of action do you want to call? Here is an example : `$dpDate.Add_SelectedDateChanged({ Write-Host "You have selected : " $dpDate.Text })`. Each time you select a date, the new date is displayed in the Powershell console

Comment: Thanks, Manu. The action I want to perform is, when a date is picked, update another textbox with the selected date. I tried by calling very simple actions from the handler but none got triggered so wondering whether "Add_SelectedDateChanged" correct event handler for datapicker.

Comment: Can you provide the code you've tried? Normally it's very easy as you have the right handler to perform this action. For example : `$dpDate.Add_SelectedDateChanged({ $textbox.Text = $dpDate.Text })` will update your textbox with the picked date.

Comment: I put code snippet in the post above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Powershell/WPF code to perform the action you're asking (tested and validated) :

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[xml]$xaml=@"
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="265" Width="371">
    <Grid>
        <DatePicker x:Name="dpDate" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="tb_FinalDate" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,55,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="149"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>

"@

$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$Window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)

#Turn XAML into PowerShell objects
$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@*[contains(translate(name(.),'n','N'),'x:Name')]]") | ForEach-Object{
    Set-Variable -Name ($_.Name) -Value $Window.FindName($_.Name)
}

$dpDate.Add_SelectedDateChanged({
    $tb_FinalDate.Text = Get-Date($dpDate.Text) -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd'
})

#Display Form
$Window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

When using `SelectedDateChanged`, you update the text of the textbox every time you pick a date :

```
$dpDate.Add_SelectedDateChanged({
    $tb_FinalDate.Text = Get-Date($dpDate.Text) -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd'
})
```

Comment: Manu, I was able to identify and fix my code with help of your working example. Thank you.